# MSysCompactError after Compact and Repair Database

Tags: ms-access-2007

Everytime I run Compact and Repair Database in Access 2010 a new table appears, named MSysCompactError. In it there's only one line with the following columns:

```
ErrorCode | ErrorDessription                       | ErrorRecID | ErrorTable
-3030     | <description in my native language>    |[]          |{170D5EC9-EFC7-473B-886C-C98F983BC28E}
```

So it appears to be a problem with one of the tables in the database, or even with one of the forms, but how do I locate this error? None of the tables or forms are named {170D5EC9-EFC7-473B-886C-C98F983BC28E}.

I am using MS Access 2007 and the tables are linked to a sharepoint server. I don't think the error is with the tables, because this error appeared only after I imported forms, querys and reports from another .accdb file and ran Compact and Repair Database.

Comment: Ugh! Access used to have an issue if you imported an object containing any code, but didn't open the code window before closing the database (seems 200 years ago?) I would create an empty database and try importing ALL objects from the 'corrupted' database. Better yet, if you have a version prior to your import of forms, try that, then import the new forms, view/compile code, save.

Comment: So the database isn't actually corrupted? I did what you said and imported all from the "corrupted" database. I didn't get any errors after Compact and Repair this time.

Comment: I believe it is still possible to have a table that has a bad row (or several), but I think the issue you had was with the code library being 'less than good'